# List of enums in EF Core

Tags: list, asp.net-core, enums, ef-core-3.1

Is it possible to use a list of enums in an project using EF Core to store the data?

My enum:

```
   public enum AudienceType
    {
        Child,
        Teen,
        [Display(Name ="Young Adult")]
        YoungAdult,
        Adult,
        Elderly
    }
```

Class using enum:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(80)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Select the target audiences")]
    public List<AudienceType> AudienceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

But when I run `add-migration AudienceType`, I get the following error:

```
PM> add-migration AudienceType
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Restaurant.AudienceTypes' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List<AudienceType>' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidatePropertyMapping(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The property 'Restaurant.AudienceTypes' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List<AudienceType>' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Update:
I see how you can use Value Conversions to handle enums, like below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var converter = new EnumToStringConverter<AudienceType>();

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Restaurant>()
        .Property(e => e.AudienceTypes)
        .HasConversion(converter);
}
```

But how do you handle a list of enums?

Comment: How you want list of enums is "represented" in the database? comma separated string or for example separate table with every enum value is a single record

Comment: I'm okay with comma separated string.

Comment: Then look at [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)

Comment: I see how you can use Value Conversions to handle enums, but how do you handle a list of enums?

Answer (score 6):

To represent list of enum values as comma separated string you can use Value Conversions.

Simplest "inline" option:

```cs
// In DbContext class
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder
      .Entity<Restaurant>()
      .Property(e => e.AudienceTypes)
      .HasConversion(
          v => string.Join(",", v.Select(e => e.ToString("D")).ToArray()),
          v => v.Split(new[] { ',' })
            .Select(e =>  Enum.Parse(typeof(AudienceType), e))
            .Cast<AudienceType>()
            .ToList()
      );
}
```

Comment: When I try this I get an error for the first parameter of HasVersion:
`cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'char'`

Comment: Replace argument of `Split` method with the char array.

Comment: If I replace the 1st argument of HasConversion with ` v => string.Join(",", v.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray())` then the `v.Split(",")`  in the second argument generates the following error:  `An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments`

Answer (score 3):

I found [this post](https://gregkedzierski.com/essays/enum-collection-serialization-in-dotnet-core-and-entity-framework-core/) helpful, which led to the following solution:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var converter = new EnumCollectionJsonValueConverter<AudienceType>();
        var comparer = new CollectionValueComparer<AudienceType>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
          .Property(e => e.AudienceTypes)
          .HasConversion(converter)
          .Metadata.SetValueComparer(comparer);
   }
```

which uses the following two classes:

```
public class EnumCollectionJsonValueConverter<T> : ValueConverter<ICollection<T>, string> where T : Enum
{
    public EnumCollectionJsonValueConverter() : base(
      v => JsonConvert
        .SerializeObject(v.Select(e => e.ToString()).ToList()),
      v => JsonConvert
        .DeserializeObject<ICollection<string>>(v)
        .Select(e => (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), e)).ToList())
    {
    }
   }

public class CollectionValueComparer<T> : ValueComparer<ICollection<T>>
{
    public CollectionValueComparer() : base((c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
      c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())), c => (ICollection<T>)c.ToHashSet())
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the convenience of the enum where I can just use it directly in a razor page:
`<select class="form-control" asp-for="Restaurant.AudienceTypes" asp-items="Model.Audiences">
        </select>`
Is  there an easy way to do that with a class?  (maybe I'm missing it)

Comment: Is `Cuisine` your enum?

Comment: Sorry, copied wrong line of code, fixed it.

Comment: That's ok, but there will be problems when the model is bound, which will make the problem complicated. So if you want to model binding, your method is indeed easier.

Answer (score 1):

Starting **EF Core 8.0**, this is all automatic now!
You don't have to do anything, and it's automatically handled.

If you want your `enum` to be a `string` follow the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#collections-of-primitives

And use this serializer options:

```
var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters =
    {
        new JsonStringEnumConverter()
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because enum is not a class, you need to write a new class to encapsulate it.

You can create a new class :

```
public class Audience
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AudienceType AudienceType { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `Restaurant`:

```
    public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(80)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Select the target audiences")]
    public List<Audience> Audiences{ get; set; }
}
```

If you need to convert it,you can convert in dbcontext.

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Audience>().Property(b => b.AudienceType).HasConversion(
            v => v.ToString(), v => (AudienceType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AudienceType), v));
```

Then migration and update database.You will get a one-to-many relationship between them.